# ? is getting replaced by jQuery1501637366954848789_1324305473579

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea and a button. button on click event i pick text from textarea, wrap it inside dDIV and append to body/previous div...it works fine. But when i enter "?" i replace it with something like "jQuery1501637366954848789_1324305473579"...i cant find why this is happening....Is there anyone who have faced the same ??

This is how i get textarea value

```
var comment = $("#comment").val();
```

This is how i wrap it

```
$('<div class="outer"><div class="inner" id="avatar"><img src="'+avatar+'" width="35" height="35"></div><div class="inner" id="comment-holder"><div id="text"><a href="mailto:'+email+'">'+name+'</a> '+comment+'</div><div class="ago">a second ago</div></div><div class="delete" style="margin-left : 2px;margin-right : 2px;">&nbsp;</div><br style="clear:both" /></div>')             
.insertBefore($('#post-comment'))
.insertAfter(".reply-holder:last")
.fadeIn("slow");
```

=========================
Got the solution myself....
made changes to ajax request, I dont know what is the relation but it worked

```
data: "action=save&comment="+temp_comment+"&email="+email+"&name="+name,
```

with

```
data: "action=save&comment="+encodeURIComponent(temp_comment)+"&email="+email+"&name="+name,
```

i am not even using temp_comment variable, Its funny. anyways problem solved :) thanks for ur time..i gonna study this later, there should be some logic behind

Comment: Please show us the _relevant_ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how jQuery generates [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requests.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with ajax/jason. I am not picking up ajax responce...i am using client side value as it is.

Comment: This would only happen if you're sending an AJAX request.  You were concatenating unescaped querystring values which looked like a JSONP URL.